# Nginx: Часть URL адреса как переменная location root

Tags: nginx

Суть такова:
Имеется директория `/var/www/dl`, в которой есть директории пользователей (chroot). В каждой директории пользователя есть директория `uploads`. Получается примерно такая структура:

- `/var/www/dl/`

  - `user1/uploads`
  - `user2/uploads`
  - `user3/uploads`

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при переходе по URL `dl.domain.com/userN/file.ext`, осуществлялся доступ к файлам в директории `/var/www/dl/userN/uploads/file.ext` (или к любому другому пути, не только к `file.ext`)

Что я пробовал:

```
location ~ ^/(\w+)/ {
        root /var/www/dl/$1/uploads;
}
```

Результат: 404

Что работает:

```
location ~ ^/(\w+)/uploads/ {
        root /var/www/dl/$1/uploads;
}

location / {
        rewrite ^/(\w+)/(.+)$ /$1/uploads/$2 break;
}
```

Возможно ли как-то привести к работе 1й вариант, который более красив и сжат?

Comment: Заменить root на alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы - замена `root` на `alias` и изменение `location`:

```
location ~ ^/(\w+)/(.+)$ {
       alias /var/www/dl/$1/uploads/$2;
}
```